# How to animate from a colored image to it's gray one?

Tags: objective-c

I am making a App cover with a color image. And I want to make this image becoming gray with animation.

I have created a gray scale image with NYXImagesKit.
But I don't know how to animate between this 2 images with UIImage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1: Create two image views with the same frame.

2: Add them as subviews to the same superview, the one above the other.

3: Set their `image` property to the colored and grayscale images, respectively.

4: Set the `alpha` property of the image view which contains the colored image to `1.0`, and set this property to `0.0` on the other one (the one displaying the grayscale image).

5: Then just fade in and out the two image views antiparallel:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    grayscaleImageView.alpha = 1.0;
    coloredImageView.alpha = 0.0;
}];
```

Comment: This is a good way to animate between 2 images. But I found the animation is not so smooth. The colored image will became dark and the gray image became brighten. It is easily distinguish these 2 two images.

Comment: I found that if I set grayscaleImageView.alpha = 0.5; before the animation. It will look more smooth. Thanks @H2CO3.